# Refreshing jsp in tiles

Tags: javascript, jsp, tiles

I am creating a webpage using jsp and tiles. My issue is that I have a timer.jsp attribute in my tiles page which acts like a countdown timer. I want its value to remain unchanged on refreshing the page. Is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to preserve the value of a client-side timer across refreshed you have to store it in the session via ajax. Something like (with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)):

```
$.post("storeInSession", {value: $("#item").val()});
```

where `/storeInSession` is mapped to a servlet (or action, depending on the framework in use) which gets the `value` request parameter and sets in as session attribute.